# \n prints an n instead of a newline when using sed in MaxOSX

Tags: sed, newlines

It's a general problem when I use `sed` but `\n` works when I use it outside of `sed`. This is one example of what I get with `sed`.

I have the file `myfile` with the following content:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

When I use this:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' myfile
```

I get this:

```
1n2n3n4n5
```

Instead of getting this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Does anybody know where the problem is?

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Can you post the output of `sed --version` and `bash --version`, please?

Comment: I have tried it and it worked, are you sure that there is a problem ?

Comment: @Networker I do have the problem but I do not know where it comes from.

Comment: @jofel Here is to reproduce myfile: echo "1 2 3 4 5" > myfile
and the output I get is $ sed 's/ /\n/g' myfile
1n2n3n4n5

Comment: @Charlie: What is your OS?

Comment: I use OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `OSX 10.8`, so your `sed` implement is `FreeBSD sed`, not `GNU sed`. So `FreeBSD sed` does not interpret `\n` as newline.

You can try:

```
$ sed 's/ /\'$'\n/g' myfile
```

`$'\n/g'` causes `bash` to interpret the string as standard escape expansion, so `\n` is converted to newline before `sed` process.

or using `tr` instead of `sed`:

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' < myfile
```

Comment: Thanks Gnouc it works perfectly when I use: $ sed 's/ /\'$'\n/g' myfile
Is GNUsed implemented for higher or lower versions of OSX?

Comment: @Charlie: you can install `gsed` for `GNU sed` implement in `OSX`.

Answer (score 3):

Gnouc is spot on about the cause, but the portable way to specify a `\n` on the right hand side of an `s///` statement is:

```
s//\
/
```

But you can also `G`et a `\n`ewline appended to the end of your pattern space from a blank hold space like:

```
G
```

And you can portably use the `y` translate operator with the `\n` on the righthand side as well. So your ...

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' myfile
```

... would do what you expected if it were written like...

```
sed 'y/ /\n/' myfile
```

... with the added advantage that it would probably also do it just a *tiny* bit faster. Though Gnouc's `tr` solution would likely be much faster still.